# How can I assign a column mean to specific values in that column of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean, assign

I want to have something like:

```
Mu = mean(X);  % column-wise means
X(X == 0) = Mu(current_column);  % assign the mean value of the current column
                                 %   to the zero-element
```

But how do I tell MATLAB that I want to assign the mean of the current column (i.e. the column the current zero-value is in) to the matrix entry at the current zero-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an array the same shape as X containing the column-wise means:

```
means = repmat(mean(X), [size(X,1) 1]);
X(X==0) = means(X==0);
```

[EDITED to add...]

Or, if the explicit expansion of the array offends you, you could do this:

```
X = bsxfun(@(x,y)(x+(x==0)*y), X, mean(X));
```

which is a bit too "clever" for my taste, but seems to be about 25% faster in the single case I tested (1000x1000 array, about 10% of which is zeros).

Comment: However, applying the second one yields: "??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." Probably because of means(X)?

Comment: Oops. I meant "mean(X)", not "means(X)". Will edit, with apologies for the way that will make nonsense of your comment :-).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized solution that's faster than using [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) and doesn't require replication of the array of column means. It simply finds the corresponding column index for every linear index to be modified, then uses that index to get the correct column mean:

```
colMeans = mean(X);    %# Get the column means
index = find(X == 0);  %# Get the linear indices of the zero values
colIndex = ceil(index./size(X,1));  %# Get the column index for each linear index
X(index) = colMeans(colIndex);      %# Reassign zeroes with the column means
```

And here's a test case:

```
>> X = randi([0 1],5)  %# Generate a random matrix of zeroes and ones

X =

     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1

>> colMeans = mean(X);
>> index = find(X == 0);
>> colIndex = ceil(index./size(X,1));
>> X(index) = colMeans(colIndex)

X =

    0.4000    1.0000    0.2000    1.0000    0.6000
    1.0000    0.8000    0.2000    1.0000    1.0000
    0.4000    1.0000    0.2000    1.0000    0.6000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.6000    1.0000
    0.4000    1.0000    0.2000    0.6000    1.0000
```

Comment: technically a nice solution, but in what context your actual mean calculation will hold? Thanks

Comment: @eat: In the context of the question. ;) In other words, I don't know *why* or *for what purpose* ptikobj wants to replace zero values with the column mean, I simply showed how it can be done efficiently.